# Installing svn: error after restarting apache

Tags: svn, apache, configuration

I've created my repository this way:

> sudo svnadmin create /svn

After restarting apache i get this error:

> Syntax error on line 16 of
>   /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dav_svn.conf:
>   DAV not allowed here

```
# dav_svn.conf - Example Subversion/Apache configuration
#
# For details and further options see the Apache user manual and
# the Subversion book.
#
# NOTE: for a setup with multiple vhosts, you will want to do this
# configuration in /etc/apache2/sites-available/*, not here.

# <Location URL> ... </Location>
# URL controls how the repository appears to the outside world.
# In this example clients access the repository as http://hostname/svn/
# Note, a literal /svn should NOT exist in your document root.
#<Location /svn>

  # Uncomment this to enable the repository
  DAV svn

  # Set this to the path to your repository
  SVNPath /svn
```

Any idea?

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`<Location /svn>` got commented out, remove the `#` in front of it.

Answer (score 5):

I struggled with this for a while before I finally figured it out.

Need to remove the # from `#<Location /svn>` and `#</Location>`

Answer (score 4):

According to the [manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dav.html), `DAV` needs to be inside a container (e.g. `Location`).